# What does the % character mean in the re-frame todomvc app todo-item function?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

The re-frame todomvc views namespace contains a function todo-item which contains the following snippet:

```
(when @editing
         [todo-edit {:class "edit"
                     :title title
                     :on-save #(dispatch [:save id %])
                     :on-stop #(reset! editing false)}])
```

the :on-save key is passed to and used in the todo-input function which contains the following snippet:

```
let [val (atom title)
        stop #(do (reset! val "")
                  (if on-stop (on-stop)))
        save #(let [v (-> @val str clojure.string/trim)]
               (if-not (empty? v) (on-save v))
               (stop))]
```

What is the meaning of the % character in the first snippet:

```
:on-save #(dispatch [:save id %])
```

and how should I interpret in the second snippet:

```
(on-save v)
```

?

Find the [todomvc views namespace here.](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/blob/master/examples/todomvc/src/todomvc/views.cljs)

Answer (score 2):

It is shorthand for this inline anonymous function definition

```
(fn [x] 
  (dispatch [:save id x]))
```

For more info please see:

- https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/fn
- https://clojure.org/reference/reader#_dispatch

Comment: Also: https://clojure.org/reference/reader#_dispatch (I tried to edit this answer, waiting for the review)